# QDataWidgetMapper insert into SQL database

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to use the `QDataWidgetMapper` to insert into a SQL database?

So far I'm using the mapper for viewing and updating but not for adding new records. Essentially I would need someway to create a `QSqlRecord` from the data associated to the `QDataWidgetMapper`.

Comment: You have an example [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405550&seqNum=3) (method `EmployeeForm::addEmployee()`)

Comment: Thank you, that's working perfectly.

Comment: @Tarod, could you please post this as answer?

Comment: @demonplus Sure! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example, but the idea is using the `insertRow` function provided by the model to insert the row that holds the mapper.

If you're using the `QDataWidgetMapper::AutoSubmit` policy, your mapper is `myMapper` and your model is called `myModel`, you could try something like this:

```
int row = myMapper->currentIndex();
myMapper->submit();
myModel->insertRow(row);
myMapper->setCurrentIndex(row);
```

This code could be called from a button (i.e. add item or something like that). You can see a full example [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405550&seqNum=3).